# How can I suppress InterpolatingFunction::dmval message?

Tags: warning-messages, interpolation

I'm getting this error again and again even though I have interpolated my function from -3 to 3.

> InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {-2.99957,-2.99957} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used

Comment: Hard to help without code we can run.

Comment: Maybe end points are not evaluated? It's certainly possible that stepsize is less than `0.00043`

Comment: post the code that generated this error

Comment: "Suppress" = `Quiet[]`, literally speaking.  There's also [`"ExtrapolationHandler"`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=ExtrapolationHandler)

Comment: It's not really an error message -- it's a warning. Without working code, it's hard to give any advice except use `Quiet` as suggested by Micheal E2.